# Using local storage with react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I have a react redux project that looks like this:

Reducer:

```
    export function contentReducer(state = { loading: true }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.RETRIEVE_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, contentResults: action.payload.results }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Action:

```
export function loginSuccess(loginResult) {
    return { type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, loginResult };
}

export function login(formData) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return submitLogin(formData).then(umvToken => {
            dispatch(loginSuccess(umvToken));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    };
}
```

The Api itself:

```
export function submitLogin(login) {
    var form = new FormData()
    form.append('userIdentifier', login.email)
    form.append('password', login.password)
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/login/login/umv",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            },
            body: form

        }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then(function (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('umvToken', token.text())
            return token
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
        })

}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        login: state.login.loginResponse
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(thunks, dispatch)
    };
}
class ConnectedHome extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
    }

    processForm(form) {
        this.props.actions.login(form)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.ButtonAppBar()}
                <LoginForm onSubmit={this.processForm} />
            </div >
        );
    }
}

const Home = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedHome);

export default Home
```

However when I try to access local storage from the home page like this:

```
var result = localStorage.getItem('umvToken')
        console.log(result)
```

I get the following message:

```
[object Promise]
```

If I replace the setting of local storage with this:

```
   localStorage.setItem('umvToken', 'test')
```

then the console.log will show test.  But it doesn't work with the actual value.  I'm not really sure how to resolve this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think `token.text()` is returning a `Promise`?

Comment: use redux-persist to keep redux data you want to have on reload https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `token.text()` returns a `Promise`, so you will need to wait for it to `resolve` to get the actual token string, i.e.

```
.then(function (token) {
  return token.text();
})
.then(tokenText => {
  localStorage.setItem('umvToken', tokenText);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From first `.then` function in api call, `return response.json();` or `return response.text();`. If you just return response, its a promise, which won't get resolved, unless you do response.json() or response.text(), depending on the type of response you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
.then(function (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('umvToken', JSON.stringify(token))
            return token
        })
```